# Check checkboxes after click link in Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, codeigniter, checkbox, foreach

I have application view like this

[image]

User's name coming with array and 0 to 8 other values coming with different array.

```
<table class="table">
<thead>

    <tr>
        <th width="60%">Name</th>
        <th>View</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>      
</thead>
<tbody>
   <?php $x = 0; ?>
        <?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>

        <tr>

            <th style="background-color: #cce5ff;"> <a style="color:#8c8c8c; cursor: pointer;" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>_<?php echo $x; ?>"> 
                    <b><?php echo $user['user']->first_name . " " . $user['user']->last_name; ?></b></a>
            </th>
            <th colspan="3" style="background-color: #cce5ff;"><a id="<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" class="select_all user_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" style="cursor: pointer;">Select All</a> </th>

        </tr>
         <tbody id="<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>_<?php echo $x; ?>" <?php if($x != 0){?> class="collapse"<?php } ?>>
        <?php foreach ($folders as $folder) { 

                $user_permissions = get_folder_permission($user['user']->id,$folder->id);

            ?>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $folder->client_name;?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="view_<?php echo $folder->id; ?>_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" class="is_check_v check_all_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" value="view" <?php if(isset($user['permission'])){if(!empty($user_permissions) && $user_permissions->can_view==1){ echo 'checked';}else{echo '';}}?>  name="per">     
                <input type="hidden" id="h_view_<?php echo $folder->id; ?>_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" name="view_permission[][<?php echo $folder->id; ?>][<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>]" value="<?php if(!empty($user_permissions)){ echo $user_permissions->can_view;}else{ echo 0; } ?>">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="edit_<?php echo $folder->id; ?>_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" class="is_check_e check_all_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" value="edit" <?php if(isset($user['permission'])){if(!empty($user_permissions) && $user_permissions->can_edit==1){ echo 'checked';}else{echo '';}}?> name="per">
                <input type="hidden" id="h_edit_<?php echo $folder->id; ?>_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" name="edit_permission[][<?php echo $folder->id; ?>][<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>]" value="<?php if(!empty($user_permissions)){ echo $user_permissions->can_edit;}else{ echo 0; } ?>">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="delete_<?php echo $folder->id; ?>_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" class="is_check_d check_all_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" value="delete" <?php if(isset($user['permission'])){if( !empty($user_permissions) && $user_permissions->can_delete==1){ echo 'checked';}else{echo '';}}?> name="per">
                <input type="hidden" id="h_delete_<?php echo $folder->id; ?>_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" name="delete_permission[][<?php echo $folder->id; ?>][<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>]" value="<?php if(!empty($user_permissions)){ echo $user_permissions->can_delete;}else{ echo 0; } ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php } ?>
         </tbody>
        <?php $x++; ?>
        <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

I want to check all "View" "Edit" "Delete" checkbox after click "Select All" link.
Every User has "Select All" link and if click it only his checkbox checked. That's I want to do, but I haven't any idea to do it.

I want to do it with Jquery.

Any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Jquery code resolved my problem.

```
$(".select_all").click(function () {
  user_id = $(this).attr('id');
  $.each($('.check_this_'+user_id),function(){
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please do not post bare code answers, also provide some commentary on what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try (Assuming that your Select All button ID is selectAll ) :

```
$('#selectAll').click(function(e){
    var table= $('.table');
    $('td input:checkbox',table).prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

Comment: but Select All link coming with array

Comment: Give a id or class to Select All link before it bind on array.